# Error in the core plot configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, xcode4.1

I'm trying to use CorePlot for an iOS application, I followed the instructions [here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1) 
But even if the `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h` file exists (CorePlot/CorePlotHeaders), the build failed  saying:

> /Users/zakariagaizi/Desktop/core_plot/core_plot/core_plot-Prefix.pch:14:36:
>   error: CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to add the relative path from your project file to the directory of CorePlot in the "Header Search Paths" so that the pre-processor can find them.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!! If i need smth else in working with, i'll ask another Q, seems that this site is very helpfull, ;););)